# Python Array Cleanup Issues

Tags: python, arrays, variables

I have a matrix-style array, that (hypothetically) looks like this:

```
mat = [[0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
imat = mat
for i in xrange(4):
    for j in xrange(4):
        imat[j][i] = mat[i][j]
for i in xrange(4):
    for j in xrange(4):
        imat[j][i] = mat[i][j]
```

The code basically switches the row/column from "mat" to "imat".

The results:
`mat:
[[0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
imat:
[[0, 2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]`
Could anyone tell me why the array items are duplicating like this?  
Also, if there is a more efficient way to do this operation, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: `imat` and `mat` both point to the same object.

Comment: `imat = map(list, zip(*mat))` is the cleanest way IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
imat = mat
```

Instead you should do this, to allocate a new 4x4 matrix at the beginning:

```
imat = [[0]*4 for _ in xrange(4)]
```

What's happening is that you didn't initialize `imat` correctly, you only assigned a reference to `mat` so both objects are one and the same, so no modification is being performed. Also, a much simpler alternative for transposing a matrix would be:

```
imat = [list(m) for m in zip(*mat)]
```

Comment: Drive-by down voters: care to comment? what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: Strange. I don't see anything wrong with it. Was there a first version of lower quality, hidden by the 5-minute edit window?

Comment: @user2357112 nope, I posted the `imat = [[0]*4 for _ in xrange(4)]` part from the beginning, but expanded on the explanation later

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, the original was a "try this" answer with no explanation.

Comment: Thanks. The `imat = [[0]*4...` works really well. You've found the problem. It now works.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, if there is a more efficient way to do this operation, that would also be appreciated.

Yes, it's called a matrix [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) operation, which in Python is done using the builtin function [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with the [*-unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
imat = zip(*mat)
```

As to why your current code doesn't work, @Óscar López has it right, doing `imat = mat` does not create a new copy of the matrix.